# Read PHP Array into NodeJS function

Tags: javascript, php, node.js

How can I "import" a PHP array into a seperate NodeJS file?

Example:

example.php

```
<?php
return array(
    'title' => 'Example Value',
    'description' => 'Example Value'
);
```

My attempt was to read it through executing the file but then I only get an empty response

```
const runner = require('child_process');
const scriptPath = 'pathtofile/filename.php';

runner.exec('php ' + scriptPath, (err, phpResponse, stderr) => {
    console.log(phpResponse);
})
```

Note that I cannot modify the PHP files.

Comment: That's quite an odd setup - why does a serverside-js process need/want to talk to a php process on the same server, and _not_ over http? `Note that I cannot modify the PHP files.` it's not going to work with the example in the question then, since the php script doesn't output anything. Please update the question with appropriate clarification :).

Answer (score 0):

Running the PHP script gets you nothing because the script doesn't output anything (there's no `echo`). So I think you need to extend the PHP script a little bit so that it does that.

```
<?php
$data = require("pathtofile/filename.php");
echo json_encode($data);
```

If you run that script from Node you should get some output that you can `JSON.parse`.

The best solution would be to store your data in JSON to begin with so both PHP and Node can read it.